# How to update the display using .map function in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a useState variable that holds log data and I'm displaying that data using `.map()`, at some particular moment, logs will be added, and I take the old variable and re affect the new value for it as the following :

```
const [logs, setLogs] = useState([])

const function1 = () => {
// some process here
 setLogs(myValues)
}
const function2 = () => {
// some process
let myNewValues = logs
// some other process
setLogs(myNewValues)
}
```

.map() function displays the `logs` just fine after the first function, but when I update the logs with `setLogs` in the second function, `.map()` doesn't get the update, it displays the old values from function1.

How can I fix this in react ?

Thanks in adavance !

Comment: Is it possible that you are mutating state instead of calling setState with a new array? In function2, try calling `setLogs([...myNewValues])`, this creates a new array from the myNewValues array, and then sets state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that you may be mutating state, instead of passing a new state.

Instead of mutating the logs array and then calling setState with the same array reference, try spreading the new values into a new array object and then calling setState.

```js
const function2 = () => {
  let myNewValues = logs;
  setLogs([...myNewValues]);
};
```

When setState is called, React looks at the object references, and sees that it received the same array reference, and then does not re-render. By passing a new array, React sees that state has changed, and will re-render accordingly.